# COMO FAÇO PRA "ANINHAR" OS DADOS QUE VEM DO BANCO?

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server, node.js, codeigniter

Não sei bem como é o nome que se dá a esse procedimento. Meus dados no banco SQL SERVER está vindo da seguinte forma:

Os dados tem um PAI (TITLE_HEADER_INF) que se repete e o FILHO(TITLE_HEADER) que nao se repete;

```
{
    "ID": 48,
    "TITLE_HEADER_INF": "(Maior Qtde. Vendas)",
    "TITLE_HEADER_INF_COLSPAN": "3",
    "TITLE_HEADER_INF_CLASS": "blue darken-3 white--text",
    "TITLE_HEADER": "Atendidas",
    "VALUE_HEADER": null,
    "TITLE_HEADER_CLASS": null
},
{
    "ID": 49,
    "TITLE_HEADER_INF": "(Maior Qtde. Vendas)",
    "TITLE_HEADER_INF_COLSPAN": "3",
    "TITLE_HEADER_INF_CLASS": "blue darken-3 white--text",
    "TITLE_HEADER": "Vendas",
    "VALUE_HEADER": null,
    "TITLE_HEADER_CLASS": null
},
```

Como faço pra retornar ele do backend(PHP codeigniter 4) ou tratar ele no front com Nodejs pra ficar da seguinte forma:

```
{
    "ID": 48,
    "TITLE_HEADER_INF": "(Maior Qtde. Vendas)",
    "TITLE_HEADER_INF_COLSPAN": "3",
    "TITLE_HEADER_INF_CLASS": "blue darken-3 white--text",
    "SUBTITLE": [
              {
  
              "TITLE_HEADER": "Vendas",
              "VALUE_HEADER": null,
              "TITLE_HEADER_CLASS": null
             },
              {
              "TITLE_HEADER": "(%) Conversão",
              "VALUE_HEADER": null,
               "TITLE_HEADER_CLASS": null
            }
       ],

},
```